# Filter dataframe based on two columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to filter out rows based on two column, one column is the ID and the other is a string of IDs (collapses by ",") that should be kept.

Example:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars2 <- mtcars%>%
  mutate(carb_l=letters[carb], # This is the ID
         carb_list="c,f,h")%>% #IDs to keep
  select(-mpg,-cyl,-disp)# for clarity


head(mtcars2)
   hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb carb_l carb_list
1 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4      d     c,f,h
2 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4      d     c,f,h
3  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1      a     c,f,h
4 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1      a     c,f,h
5 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2      b     c,f,h
6 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1      a     c,f,h
```

Expected output:

```
> mtcars2%>%filter((carb_l %in%c("c","f","h")))
   hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb carb_l carb_list
1 180 3.07 4.07 17.4  0  0    3    3      c     c,f,h
2 180 3.07 3.73 17.6  0  0    3    3      c     c,f,h
3 180 3.07 3.78 18.0  0  0    3    3      c     c,f,h
4 175 3.62 2.77 15.5  0  1    5    6      f     c,f,h
5 335 3.54 3.57 14.6  0  1    5    8      h     c,f,h
```

Comment: One way can be `mtcars2 %>% rowwise() %>% filter(grepl(carb_l, carb_list))`

Comment: Use `strsplit` as for example in `mtcars2 %>% filter((carb_l %in% unlist(strsplit(carb_list, ','))))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rowwise()` and `grepl` , i.e.

```
mtcars2 %>% 
 rowwise() %>% 
 filter(grepl(carb_l, carb_list))

# A tibble: 5 × 10
# Rowwise: 
     hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb carb_l carb_list
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>    
1   180  3.07  4.07  17.4     0     0     3     3 c      c,f,h    
2   180  3.07  3.73  17.6     0     0     3     3 c      c,f,h    
3   180  3.07  3.78  18       0     0     3     3 c      c,f,h    
4   175  3.62  2.77  15.5     0     1     5     6 f      c,f,h    
5   335  3.54  3.57  14.6     0     1     5     8 h      c,f,h
```

Comment: Thank you! This answer works for different elements in ```carb_list```. Example: if the input has added ```mtcars2[1,10] <- "a,b,d"```, then this method would also keep the first row.

Answer (score 2):

```
mtcars2 %>% 
   filter(carb_l %in% strsplit(mtcars2$carb_list[1], ",")[[1]])
               hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb carb_l carb_list
Merc 450SE    180 3.07 4.07 17.4  0  0    3    3      c     c,f,h
Merc 450SL    180 3.07 3.73 17.6  0  0    3    3      c     c,f,h
Merc 450SLC   180 3.07 3.78 18.0  0  0    3    3      c     c,f,h
Ferrari Dino  175 3.62 2.77 15.5  0  1    5    6      f     c,f,h
Maserati Bora 335 3.54 3.57 14.6  0  1    5    8      h     c,f,h
```